# How to dynamically wire preferences items to radio buttons

Tags: android, preferences, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preference

I would like to know how to modify preferences items dynamically. I have this preference screen with various items in it and i have a dialog box with Radio Buttons that i can delete and add new Radio Buttons. I need to bind my Preference items to all my Radio Buttons and change the values when a Radio Button in dialog is pressed.

Is this possible considering the fact that radio buttons are created on the fly?